# How to move pannel up when keyboard appears in unity input field

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am using unity canvas to design a menue but when the keyboard appears the screen does not move up is there a way to move the screen up when the keyboard appears 
[The screen i have without the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CfdT.jpg)

[The screen i have with android keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWRL0.jpg)

Is there a way around it where i can move the whole panel up when i click on input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Unity canvas is probably overlapping your menu, the canvas is considering it as "displayed" but as a matter of fact it is not. What you need is a way tell Unity that your area is currently smaller, and make the remaining part scrollable. I strongly suggest you to take a look at [THIS](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect) scripting tutorial about ScrollRect in Unity, as well as the documentation about Screen  TouchScreenKeyboard classes. I am not familiar with how Unity works with Android, but you may have to calculate your current visible space by yourself. [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html) link can help you to start getting the proper sizes.

Comment: i found [This] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072522/how-to-resize-view-when-touchscreen-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-with-unity). but it didn't work